# Lengthy operation in Ruby-on-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am face to face with the following situation.

A user clicks on a link in order to generate a text or XML. I have a method `generateXMLfile` in my controller which reads data from a db table and creates a hash or array. After reading and creating are finished I send data using `send_file` method.

The file generating process may take time between 5 and 25 seconds (huge data), so what I want to do is to display the "Please wait" message with waiting gif animation while the request is being processed, and display the success message upon successful completion.

I know how to implement similar operations such as, for example, a file upload using pure AJAX, but I don't know how to do it in Rails.

Has anyone dealt with the similar problem?  What is the best practice or Rails way to perform this operation? Any suggestions or recommendations?

**UPDATE**:

```
def generateXMLfile

    #lengthy operation
    (1..100000000).each do 
    end

    sample_string = "This is a sample string\ngenerated by generateXML method.\n\n   Bye!"

    send_data sample_string, 
            :type => 'charset=utf-8; header=present', 
            :disposition => "attachment; filename=sample.txt"
  end
```

Comment: Just handle click on the link with javascript. Show the animation and start downloading the file via ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind call like this using UJS.

```
<%= link_to "send file",generateXMLfile_path, :remote => true, :id => "send_file" %>

$('#send_file').bind('ajax:beforeSend', function() {
  $('#please wait').show();
});

$('#send_file').bind('ajax:complete', function() {
  $('#please_wait').hide();
  $('flash').show();
});
```

You can also use `generateXMLfile.js.erb` for complete action.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I guess you should remove `:remote => true`.

Comment: if I remove the `:remote => true` then javascript part of the code does not work, but `send_file works`. If I add `:remote => true` then javascript code works but `send_data` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to have 5-25 seconds requests. 
It can render your application unresponsive when multiple users start uploading files simultaneously. Or you can hit a timeout limit on your web server.
You should use some background processing tool, here are some options:

- delayed job (https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)
- sidekiq (http://sidekiq.org/)
- resque (http://resquework.org/)

Delayed job is the simplest one, Sidekiq and Resque are a little bit more complex and they require you to install Redis.

When background processing finishes you can use some Websocket-based tool to send a message to your frontend. Pusher (http://pusher.com/) is one of such tools.

Comment: Good idea. I am aware of sidekiq and I will definitely shift to one of these libraries. But I first want to start from simple AJAX processing examples and move towards advanced techniques.